# Jenkins add credentials window not works

Tags: git, jenkins, credentials

I want to access with the Jenkins to my git repository. The Jenkins can access to the server but not log in. If I want to add credentials the folowing window will open. Why I can't add username and password?

Image:
http://goo.gl/oDCuVG

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood your question correctly or not. But see if this helps you. If you are asking about accessing github from jenkins, when you are creating job, in configuration section, you will have "source code management" section where you need to select 'git' and provide your git repo location and also username and password.